# Ubuntu snappy with Raspberry PI

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu-core

I just have a question I installed Ubuntu snappy in Raspberry Pi2 and I'm trying to install Xen Hypervisor over it I was trying to use the regular method to install it for Ubuntu but it did't work for me I get the error:

xen-hypervisor-amd64 failed to install : snappy package not found

any help or advice would be really appreciated
Thanks in advance

Xen-Hypervisor installation method for Ubuntu:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen

Answer (score 1):

apt-get commands do not work on Ubuntu Core (snappy). Instead you will need to use snappy install commands.

I do not believe that xen hypervisor is available on snappy at this stage though. So you would need to talk with the team behind it to find out if they can make a port available.

Answer (score 0):

The amd64 packages are for regular 64-bit processors, and the Pi has an Arm processor. The packages for 64-bit processors will simply not be understandable for an arm processor.

But furthermore, a hypervisoris probably not a good way to go for a Pi. Virtual machines take up a lot of RAM memory, and the Pi has precious little. You might want tolook into some sort of multi-boot solution instead, where it might be possible to boot different OS'es on the Pi, but just one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Although the RPi2 has Cortex-A7cores, which have virtualisation extensions in it, including a virtualised Generic Interrupt Controller (GIC). AFAIK the overall SoC does not use the GIC to route/control interrupts but instead such things are under the control of another interrupt controller which s part of the GPU (which is actually in control of the system like with RPi1 and RPi2) and is not a GIC and is not virtualisable.

Xen requires a virtualis(ed|able) GIC, and AFAIK the GPU interrupt 
controller does not meet the requirements.